# I am making an app and I require to use the interface Parcelable but facing issues and not sure how to implement it

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to coding and to java and android. I am making an app that has multiple canvas views (where a person can draw lines with their finger) in multiple fragments (requested to be like this). I have managed to get the fragments to work and to draw lines on each canvas. Next, I want to be able to save the lines drawn by the user when the user goes to a different fragment or closes the app and when the user comes back to a fragment, the drawing for that fragment will still be there, and can continue editing it by adding more lines or clear it by hitting Clear, the same should happen for other fragments that should have their respective drawings.

I was previously told about the interface *Parcelable* and have made some steps to implement it but I am finding it hard to understand what I am doing and having trouble reading in an ArrayList. The error is stating that it is expecting *ClassLoader* but being provided with an *ArrayList* (I hope in the right place), and that's if I make the getter static but that creates an error: *Non-static field 'paths' cannot be referenced from a static context* in the getter in the PaintView class (this controls the drawing). I get a similar static context message for the readArrayList method in the FingerPath class. Once this is figured out, I will need to find out how to bring the relevant, saved drawing back to the canvas when the fragment is opened which I am not sure how, I think when the *Bundle* isn't equal to null but not sure.

I'll show the code below (right now it is on a test app)

**FingerPath class**

```
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FingerPath implements Parcelable {

public int color;
public boolean emboss;
public boolean blur;
public int strokeWidth;
public Path path;

public FingerPath(int color, boolean emboss, boolean blur, int strokeWidth, Path path) {
    this.color = color;
    this.emboss = emboss;
    this.blur = blur;
    this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    this.path = path;

}



protected FingerPath(Parcel in) {
    color = in.readInt();
    emboss = in.readByte() != 0;
    blur = in.readByte() != 0;
    strokeWidth = in.readInt();

    //line below causing me issues
    path = in.readArrayList(PaintView.getPaths());

}

public static final Creator<FingerPath> CREATOR = new Creator<FingerPath>() {
    @Override
    public FingerPath createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new FingerPath(in);
    }

    @Override
    public FingerPath[] newArray(int size) {
        return new FingerPath[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeInt(color);
    parcel.writeByte((byte) (emboss ? 1 : 0));
    parcel.writeByte((byte) (blur ? 1 : 0));
    parcel.writeInt(strokeWidth);
    //parcel.writeParcelableArray(PaintView.getPaths(), 0);


}




}
```

**PaintView**

*Controls what happens when the user starts drawing*

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BlurMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.EmbossMaskFilter;
import android.graphics.MaskFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class PaintView extends View {

public static int BRUSH_SIZE = 10;
public static final int DEFAULT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
public static int DEFAULT_BG_COLOR = Color.GRAY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
private float mX, mY;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mPaint;
private ArrayList<FingerPath> paths = new ArrayList<>();
private int currentColor;
private int backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
private int strokeWidth;
private boolean emboss;
private boolean blur;
private MaskFilter mEmboss;
private MaskFilter mBlur;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);



public PaintView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);

}

public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);

    mPaint.setColor(DEFAULT_COLOR);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
    mPaint.setAlpha(0xff);

    mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] {1, 1, 1}, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
    mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(5, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);

}



//the getter in question
public ArrayList getPaths() {
    return paths;

}

public void init(DisplayMetrics metrics) {
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    currentColor = DEFAULT_COLOR;
    strokeWidth = BRUSH_SIZE;
}

public void normal() {
    emboss = false;
    blur = false;
}



public void clear() {
    backgroundColor = DEFAULT_BG_COLOR;
    paths.clear();
    normal();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    mCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor);

    for (FingerPath fp: paths) {
        mPaint.setColor(fp.color);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(fp.strokeWidth);
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);

        if (fp.emboss)
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
        else if (fp.blur)
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);

        mCanvas.drawPath(fp.path, mPaint);
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

    canvas.restore();
}

private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
    mPath = new Path();
    FingerPath fp = new FingerPath(currentColor, emboss, blur, strokeWidth, mPath);
    paths.add(fp);

    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x-mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y-mY);

    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}

private void touchUp() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            touchStart(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            touchMove(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            touchUp();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

*Here's an example of a fragment*

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class LineLHwFragment extends Fragment {

private PaintView paintView;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_line_l_hw, container, false);
        paintView = v.findViewById(R.id.lineLPaintView);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    paintView.init(metrics);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return v;

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.normal:
            paintView.normal();
            return true;

        case R.id.clear:
            paintView.clear();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelableArrayList("line test", paintView.getPaths());
}


}
```